# How to determine when focus leaves an HTML form (i.e. no child of the form has focus anymore)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-events, focusout

For example, I have an HTML form element with a textarea, and two buttons as child elements.  How can I detect when the focus goes from one of those three elements, to an element OTHER THAN one of those three.  In other words, how do I detect when focus leaves the form, so I can dismiss it automatically?

I thought I could use the `focusout` event on the form to figure out when focus no longer belonged to one of its child elements, but the object gaining the focus doesn't seem to be accessible from the `focusout` event, so I have no way to checking whether focus is just going from the textarea to one of the buttons, for example.

The `relatedObject`, `fromElement`, and `toElement` properties are all undefined.

Comment: On a side note, this is easy to do in Flash, because ActionScript 3 actually has its act together, and populates the relatedObject and target fields of its FocusEvent object.  Wtf JavaScript/DOM?

Comment: Yes, I'm using jQuery, but that's largely irrelevant, as it just provides shortcuts to bind events.  The underlying HTML/DOM event model is the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

While i fear this approach may have subtle errors, it's the best i know of:

- register on the form's `focusout` event (not `blur`, because the latter does not bubble)
- register a 0-delayed function via `setTimeout`, so the focus transfer is handled
- in the timeouted function, check if `document.activeElement` is a descendent of your form. If not, fire.

Here is a example implementation:

```js
$('#yourform').on('focusout', function(evt) {
  var self = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (self.has($(document.activeElement)).length == 0) {
      alert('leave');
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='yourform'>
  <input type='text'>
  <input type='text'>
</form>


<input type='text'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".myform");

document.onclick = () => {

  // query selecting the form element and checking for the
  // css :focus pseudo class inside the form element
  if (!form.querySelector(":focus")) {
  
    // this console log would run when any placeholder in the form is not focused 
    console.log("form dismissed.")
  }
}
```

```css
.myform {
  padding: 10px;
  background: blueviolet;
  color: #fff;
}
.myform * {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="myform">
  when not selecting the placeholders this will log a msg to the console
  <input value="select here" type="text"/>
  <input value="select here" type="text"/>
  <textarea>Select here</textarea>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you noticed in the snippet above you could use the `element.querySelector(":focus")` to check whether the contents of the form has focus or not. This approach completely works fine.

( *vote if you found this answer useful to you* )

Answer (score -1):

correct name is "blur"

```
function setBlur()
{
   var elements = document.getElementByTagName('input');
   for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
      elements[i].setAttribute('onfocus', 'callme(this)');
}
function callme(el)
{
   var _id = el.getAttribute('id');
   if(_id != "textarea_id' && _id != "button_1_id" && _id != "button_2_id")
        callYourMethodToHandleFocusOutsideYourForm();
}
body.onload = function() { setBlur(); }
```

this will do the trick

you can do it also for textarea just apply `document.getElementByTagname('textarea')` and loop through array.

Comment: No, that won't do the trick.  First of all, that method won't handle the condition where the user clicks in a blank area on the page (i.e. somewhere outside the form).  The input still loses focus, but nothing will happen, because it's not listening for "onfocus" on anything but inputs in your example.  Secondly, this requires me to know the exact IDs of the objects in the form, which could be dynamically generated and unknown at design-time.  Third, this doesn't restrict to a specific container form -- there may be more than one form on the page -- it just uses the whole document.